# Make image inside div take the always the same amount of space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id=“parent”>
    <div id = "child1">
       <img src="123"/> 
   </div>
   <div id = "child2"> 
      <p> Some text1 </p>
      <p> Some text2 </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have parent div with fixed height. Parent div always have 2 child containers:

- 1 clild - div with image
- 2 child - div with some data

The image inside the container can be different in size. Sometimes, when image is larger, it takes more space inside `#child1` and my `#child2` with text becoming only half-visible. I can see the "Some text1 " paragraph, but not "Some text2".

How can I make my image inside `#child1` take always same % of space inside `#parent`? (Probably, by zooming it in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `#child` and `#child2` width, then make the `img` element's width 100% of the parent.

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
}

.child {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=“parent”>
    <div class="child">
       <img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/1280x868/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fdam%2Fimageserve%2F42977075%2F960x0.jpg%3Ffit%3Dscale"/> 
   </div>
   <div class="child"> 
      <p> Some text1 </p>
      <p> Some text2 </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is awesome for this. I have included comments in the CSS that explain what each line does.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* border & padding are included in calculation of width */
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  /* flexbox layout! */
  background: papayawhip;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  /* this is the layout of the child elements realtive to the flex container .parent, shorthand for flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 50%; Think of flex-basis as the width you want the items to start at */
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
  padding: 20px;
  /* some space around the edges inside */
}

#child1 {
  display: flex;
  /* give the child1 wrapper flexbox layout as well */
  align-items: center;
  /* vertical alignment */
  justify-content: center;
  /* horizontal alignment */
}

#child1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="child1" class="child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div id="child2" class="child">
    <p> Some text1 </p>
    <p> Some text2 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing height of the children and using background image will help. `overflow` will make sure that the height of the child does not go beyond **250px**

```
#parent { 
  height:500px; 
}
#child1, #child2 { 
  height: 250px; 
  overflow:auto; 
  width:100%;
}
#child1 { 
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1" style="background-image:url('path');"></div>
    <div id="child2">Text</div>
</div>
```